# PHP Looping through to combine results in

Tags: php

Need some help, keep going back and forth of ways to possibly do this. I’m creating a basic survey screen in FileMaker and using PHP to get my results. I need to collate the survey data in a usable format so I can chart the data. When I query FileMaker using PHP it returns a rather large array of data. With the code below I have managed to output the following:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $question) 
{
    echo $question->getField('Question').' - '. $question->getField('Answer').'<br />';
}
```

My output

```
Has the noise around the surrounding are increased with the new store opening – Strongly Agree
Has the noise around the surrounding are increased with the new store opening – Strongly Agree
Has the noise around the surrounding are increased with the new store opening – Agree
Has the noise around the surrounding are increased with the new store opening – Disagree
Has the noise around the surrounding are increased with the new store opening – Strongly Disagree
Do you think the store closing earlier at weekend would help with noise levels - Strongly Disagree
Do you think the store closing earlier at weekend would help with noise levels - Strongly Disagree
Do you think the store closing earlier at weekend would help with noise levels - Strongly Agree
Do you think the store closing earlier at weekend would help with noise levels - Strongly Disagree
Do you think the store closing earlier at weekend would help with noise levels – Disagree
```

I now need to collate this data, whether it be in as an array or json format. I’m trying to use the format below as it looks the most simple.

```
[Question][StronglyAgree][Agree][Disagree][StronglyDisagree]
[Has the noise around the surrounding are increased with the new store opening][2][1][1][2]
[Do you think the store closing earlier at weekend would help with noise levels][1][0][1][3]
Etc….
```

The way I would do it in a FileMaker script is to loop though the $data array, comparing the question on the current pointer to the last question (last pointer). If its different put the value of question in the question array variable. That would obtain all the unique questions I have. Looking at php documentation I found array_unique which would do all of this for me however I can’t get it to work with my foreach ($data as $key => $question).

Once I have got my unique questions I would then loop though the $data again compared against the question I am searching on counting all the Strongly Agree and then placing this value into the first [] against the question. Again I would loop 3 other times for each question for Agree, Disagree…

Is there someone out there that knows of a tutorial or answer that will help me combine these results together with the count of answers with the question. Not too bothered about the format, something like the following would work

```
Has the noise around the surrounding are increased with the new store opening,2,1,1,2
Or 
{“Question":"John", “Strongly Agree”:2,“Agree”:1,“Disagree”:1,“Strongly Disagree”:2 },
```

As a last resort, I was thinking of querying the database 4 times for each question, but that would be too many calls and kill performance.Storing the returned values into a variable formatted above somehow. Sounds a little excessive, but probably the method I may end up going as its a bit more easier to understand than loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the question as array-key?

```
/*
 * @var array $surveyResults: [
 *  "My Question" => [
 *      "Question" => "My Question" ,
 *      "Strongly Agree" => 2,
 *      ... etc ...
 *  ]
 * ]
 */
$surveyResults = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $question) {
    // if we have not processed this question before, add it to the survey results
    if (!isset($surveyResults[$question->getField('Question')])) {
        $surveyResults[$question->getField('Question')] = [
            "Question"          => $question->getField('Question'),
            "Strongly Agree"    => 0,
            "Agree"             => 0,
            "Disagree"          => 0,
            "Strongly Disagree" => 0
        ];
    }
    // count answer
    $surveyResults[$question->getField('Question')][$question->getField('Answer')]++:
}

echo json_encode($surveyResults);
```

That should give a result like you suggested.

Comment: Thank you Jojo for replying with your code. Makes total sense when you mention it like that, knew I didn't need to make so many calls to the db but lack of experience. I've just tried your code, I seem to be having trouble with the json_encode line producing undefined index error. Commented that line out and did a print_r($surveyResults) to see how its populated and that produced results as expected :) I need to do more reading up on json_encode and figure out whats going on.